# card game desing , oop of classes

Tags: oop

i want to write a 4 player card game ... my classes are:

1-main

2-card

3-dealer (has an array of card object and array.length = 52)

4-player (has an array of card object and array.length=13//each player has 13 cards)

my question is it a good job to add a class "deck" that has an array of 13 card object or simply add this array of 13 card object to player class ?

**edited-** is there any class needed to check who is the winner and when the game is finish or i should implement this part of code in the main class ?

Comment: With a design like this, you're going to have to make sure that there is only one copy of each Card. Having a Deck class is useful because it is the 'owner' of all the cards and passes each Card to the Player via a Deal() method. The Deck class will have to mark each card object with whether that card is still in the deck or not.

Your Dealer object is probably the same as a Deck object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would rather use the term `Hand` than `Deck`, especially if there's a dealer involved, but that's your call. The important part is to stick with one term and follow the real domain terms (e.g. if you had game experts and they were saying the player's hand, then this should be reflected in code).

It's great to make implicit concepts explicit, so I would definitely have a `Hand` class. It would make a natural home for any behaviors related to the player's hand and it can be used to enforce invariants (e.g. enforcing that a hand is always constituted of 13 cards initially).

Note that the invariant enforcement could also be made in the `Dealer.deal` method. You could make the `Hand` constructor package protected and the `deal` method would become a factory for the `Hand`.

Finally, I think you are missing a `Game` concept. The `main` method could just go in a `GameBootstrap` class or something similar and would form your Composition Root. The `Game` class would be responsible for the game state and rules.

Answer (score 1):

Either approach would work.

If going for the second approach, you'll need to create non-private methods in `Deck` to do whatever you want with the deck from outside the class, such as a method that gets the top card from the deck, or one to shuffle it.

Comment: I don't know about you, but my real decks of cards don't magically shuffle themselves. :P It's usually an external process like a dealer or machine.

Comment: @Casey I imagine trying to simulate the real world too closely from a OOP design perspective won't end well (perhaps unless you're building a real-world simulation). Of course there will be scenario's where having a deck have its own shuffle method won't make sense (for example, if you want different dealers to shuffle the deck differently), but that was just an example anyway.